# Combining HTML element for each ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am doing a simple ajax call and updating the response to a div with some HTML formatting, but the thing is I have to trigger ajax call in every 3 seconds and bring update the response, do I need to structure every time or how do I combine the HTML for each response?

```js
let x = "https://mocki.io/v1/9d98868c-8d9d-49ab-97e1-764e7c33b3e5"
let joinedType = null;

setInterval(() => {
  getApiData()
}, 3000);

function getApiData() {
  $.ajax(x, {
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    timeout: 3000,
    success: (data, textStatus, xhr) => {
      if (data.messages.length > 0) {
        joinedType = data.messages[0].type;
        console.log(joinedType);
      }
    },
    error: (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) => {
      console.log('I am not working well!')
    }
  });

  var chatBlock = '<div class="ctc-container">' +
    '<div class="ctc-messages-container">' +
    '<img src="" alt="Avatar">' +
    '<p class="ctc-messages">' + joinedType + '</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<span class="time-right">11:00</span>' +
    '</div>';
  $(".ctc-chat-messages").append(chatBlock);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ctc-chat-messages">
  ..every time ctc-container will be appended next to each block in every 3 seconds.
</div>
```

Here is the Example code as well as the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/bcdLkj64/15/)

Comment: Don't use `async: false`. Put the code that appends to the DOM inside the `success` function.

Comment: Also your need to make an AJAX request to update data every 3 seconds is highly questionable for a lot of reasons. If you need to keep the UI and server state in sync, use websockets.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the suggestion, I only have question, like I am doing for one field append, do I need to create the HTML for each field?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan we'll not be using this settimeout, its just for testing..

Comment: you can also use backticks and template literals for your HTML output, which not only gives you greater freedom (no more ' + ') but also makes it visually easier to identify the variables within

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a callback method on succes. A simplified example derived from your code:

```js
let x = "https://mocki.io/v1/9d98868c-8d9d-49ab-97e1-764e7c33b3e5";

getApiData();
// ^ start right away

function getApiData() {
  $.ajax(x, {
    type: 'GET',
    timeout: 3000,
    success: data => {
      if (data.messages.length > 0) {
        appendResult(data.messages[0].type);
        // ^ call appendResult
      }
    },    
    error: _ => console.log('I am not working well!')
    
  });

  function appendResult(joinedType) {
    $(".ctc-chat-messages").append(`
        <p class="ctc-messages">${joinedType}`
    );
    
    setTimeout(getApiData, 3000);
    // continue every 3 secs.
  }
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ctc-chat-messages">
  ..every time ctc-container will be appended next to each block in every 3 seconds.
</div>
```